# how to export two components in one Name in typescript , like export Form, I can use Form.Item

Tags: typescript

now I have two components, Menu and MenuItem.  I want to export Menu at the same time to use MenuItem.

```
 import Menu from "./Menu";
 import MenuItem from "./MenuItem";
 Menu.Item = MenuItem;
 export default Menu;
```

the error is: Property 'MenuItem' does not exist on type 'FunctionComponent'
so how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

If you want MenuItem to be available on Menu, then you have to add it as a static property on Menu. But then it can't be typed as a FC. You would have to extend the FC with a property

```
interface MenuType<Props> = FC<Props> & { Item: FC }
```